# Domains and shares(Share a DVD-ROM drive?)

Tags: network-shares, active-directory

As a part of my college studies, I configured an AD DS for me to put around and enjoy while my review license lasts. My wife had recently purchased a laptop with out a DVD-ROM and with a puny 32 GB SSD. I decided to make available a tower to serve her both storage space and a disc drive. I get how to administer shares with those two resources, what I'm having troubles with is, is it possible to create and ad-hoc network between her laptop and the computer tower? I'm not sure if a computer on a domain has options other than running router and remote services to share outside of a domain.

Resources on the network:

- Linksys 54G AP (Wifi physical destroyed and used only as an unmanaged
  switch)
- Tower: Windows Server 2008 R2 (gig port/100 MB port)
- Laptop: Windows 7 Ultimate (WiFi/Gig port:Server remote management tools)
- Tower: Windows 7 Ultimate *intended for the wife.(WNIC 802.11g:100 MB
  port)
- Laptop: Windows 8.1 OEM (WiFi).

Can some one please refer me to a link that explains how to properly style a question. I hate leaving these things globbed up with no style and formatting.

Comment: Windows has File and Printer sharing.  On the tower create a folder and right click folder **Share with**->**Specific People**.  For testing add **Everyone** and give them **Read/Write** permissions.  From the laptop type \\tower\sharename  in windows explorer or the run dialog.

Comment: "Can some one please refer me to a link that explains how to properly style a question. I hate leaving these things globbed up with no style and formatting." - press the red `?` icon or read https://superuser.com/editing-help

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you. That clears things up nicely for me.

Comment: @cybernard I'll give that a try.